# How do I use the Outlook Object Model to set the encoding for a single outbound email?

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook, outlook-addin

I am using the Outlook object model to send messaegs and some have Japanese characters. The recipient receives them as letters and numbers so I'd like to send these messages using utf-8 encoding. I can configure this for all messages in Outlook Advanced options but would prefer not to change that setting whenever I need to do this (I leave at Western European ISO normally).

How do I create a message and set the encoding? I tried using the InternetCodePage value but that didn't work. The value would be set to 65001 as shown below but as soon as I set the htmlbody property, the value would change to ASCII.

I'm using PowerShell and welcome ideas.

```
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$mail.InternetCodepage = "65001"
$Mail.HTMLBody = $HTMLWithJapaneseCharacters
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the right code page for the whole email, all Unicode characters inside the HTML body must be [HTML-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references).

Comment: Great, thanks! I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to do that in PowerShell but couldn't do it. How do I do that?

If it matters at all, the output I see in the message replaces the Japanese characters with things like &#20363

Comment: yes, Unicode characters in the form of &#20363; is what you want.